# How to size and split hvac ducts appropriately?

Tags: hvac, ducts, green, erv

I am installing an HRV.  A Broan/vanmar/vanee self balancing model.

-peak cfm is 160, average cfm will be about 90cfm

-It has 6in ports for fresh and return air.

-i would like to split both of them into 3-4 ducts. A fresh air for each of the two master bedrooms, and one fresh air for the living space. Then a return for each of the two master baths and another return in the kitchen/living area.  If you guys think i could split 1 more duct off i know where i would put them.

The hrv will be on one corner in the house in a mechanical room and the distances to the rooms will be about 20 to 30 feet except for one return from a master bath that is on the other side of the wall so 7 feet

***My question is
How should i split the ducts and what size ducting should i use to accommodate the above?***

My current plan
Run two 6 insulated sheet metal ducts into the attic space and split in the attic. Then all ducts will be 6in insulated aluminum flexi.  As i understand it, it is better use slightly oversized ducts and balance with dampers than undersize.

To split:  simple duct wye splitters and run them in line.
[image: wye splitter 6in to 6in]

The furthest/largest room will get the duct most "inline" duct.

Mastic tape used throughout to join ducts and insulation.

They will end in an register diffuser with an integrated damper.  Return airs will have a filter

One thing I did think about doing was building a couple of small insulated plenums and running the ducts off of those as that is something within my abilities.  But if the wye splitters are acceptable then i will use them as that is a lot easeir.

Thanks!